# Backendless Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, backendless

I try to use Backendless for a windows phone 8.1 app but it does not work i don't know why 
I created a folder 'lib' in the solution and put Backendless.dll in it  but always give this message 
"Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Backendless.DLL
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Phone, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
 here is the code of the Exception

```
 try {
                Backendless.URL = "http://api.backendless.com";
                Backendless.InitApp("5B4CD0EF-C1-5F50-FF9C-CC89F7ADB500", "05A239D7-F142-166-6-FF9A7A52B7C71600", "v1");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue at the moment. Have you had any success finding a solution? Do you have the same issue with Universal (Windows 10) apps? Did you try downloading the code from GitHub and compiling it for yourself to target 8.1? This is my next port of call, I'll come back and post if I manage to work something out.

Comment: i worked with Rest api and i created php files to get any data needed